# Print DataFrame as comma separated values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame similar to the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

city_names = pd.Series(['San Francisco', 'San Jose', 'Sacramento'])
population = pd.Series([852469, 1015785, 485199])

df = pd.DataFrame({'City name': city_names, 'Population': population})
```

I'm trying to get this output:

```
San Fransisco, 852469

San Jose, 1015785

Sacramento, 485199
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Note that if you're OK with the commas not having spaces after them, `df.to_csv(index=False)` also works.

Comment: Good point @MateenUlhaq, that makes me wonder whether OP wanted CSV output in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question the below prints a dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd

city_names = pd.Series(['San Francisco', 'San Jose', 'Sacramento'])
population = pd.Series([852469, 1015785, 485199])

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'City name': city_names, 'Population': population })

the_dict = df.to_dict()
```

This will print a dictionary

```
print(the_dict)

{'City name': {0: 'San Francisco', 1: 'San Jose', 2: 'Sacramento'}, 'Population': {0: 852469, 1: 1015785, 2: 485199}}
```

In saying that your desired output looks likecomma-separated values.

Comment: ok maybe I asked it wrong.  How do I print one line at a time?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = "\n".join(", ".join(map(str, xs)) for xs in df.itertuples(index=False))
>>> print(s)

San Francisco, 852469
San Jose, 1015785
Sacramento, 485199
```

Comment: Since the index is thrown away, you could switch from `.iterrows()` to `.itertuples(index=False)`. The performance would likely be much better, too.

Comment: @AMC Thanks, I ran some performance tests and it looks like it's 60x faster. Also, it seems to be slightly faster than "Method 2" (by 1.3x) and "Method 1" (by 5x).

Comment: _Also, it seems to be slightly faster than "Method 2" (by 1.3x) and "Method 1" (by 5x)._ Hmm, I'm a bit surprised, since my 2nd method and yours are quite similar.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to avoid `.iterrows()`, since it tends to be sluggish.

---

#### Method 1:

```py
'\n'.join(df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x), axis=1))
```

#### Method 2:

```py
'\n'.join([', '.join(elem) for elem in df.astype(str).itertuples(index=False)])
```